# TypeError getElementsByTagName is not a function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting to the source of this problem. Basically the error message I am getting in my console is:

```
TypeError: $(...).getElementsByTagName is not a function
```

When I click through to the line it is occuring on it is here:

```
var inputs = $('directoryresults').getElementsByTagName('input');
```

I'm not sure why this is happening as I have included `jQuery` in the header of the page itself:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp

Comment: a jQuery object is not a DOM node.

Comment: This jQuery tutorial might be worth having a look at: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/, http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

The object returned by the jQuery constructor doesn't have the `.getElementsByTagName()` method.

---

`$('selector')` returns a jQuery object. `.getElementsByTagName()` is a native JavaScript method of DOM elements.

To look for elements with a certain tagname using the jQuery object you currently have:

```
var inputs = $('directoryresults input');
// OR
var inputs = $('directoryresults').find('input');
```

To get a like-for-like node list that `.getElementsByTagName()` would return (note this isn't exactly the same, this will return an array where `.getElementsByTagName()` will return a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)):

```
var inputs = $('directoryresults input').get();
```

Note: `directoryresults`, I am assuming, is either a class or id of a DOM element. Either way you'll want to **amend the selector above**

Comment: "$('selector') creates a jQuery collection". I'd say a jQuery *object* instead of collection.

Answer (score 5):

You are ussing a DOM API mixed with jQuery API sintax:

it's `document.getElementsByTagName('input');`

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. It would be more correct to say that they are mixing jQuery API and DOM API.

Comment: @FelixKling yes you are right, I don't know Why I Wrote that. Updated

Answer (score 5):

`getElementsByTagName` is a method you will find on Element and Document objects.

`$('directoryresults')` will return a jQuery object (containing any `<directoryresult>` elements … so nothing if you are working on an HTML document).

to use `getElementsByTagName`, you need to extract the elements from the jQuery object:

```
$('directoryresults')[0].getElementsByTagName
```

The above will only get the first element from the jQuery object (and it assumes that there will be at least one element) so you should probably replace the hard coded `[0]` with a `for` loop.

That said, you should generally use the `find` method instead:

```
$('directoryresults').find('input')
```

… or just use a descendant combinator in the first place:

```
$('directoryresults input')
```

As noted earlier, `directoryresults` won't find anything in a valid HTML document. You probably want to prefix it with `.` or `#` depending on what you are actually trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

**The first error is not specific if directoryresults is a class or an ID**

Nor do you tell if a target item or the item you wish to call

---

If you use jQuery by TagName type this:

```
var inputs = $('input');
```

if you want put values in a div

```
$.each(inputs, function(){
    $('div').append( $(this).val() );
});
```