# D3 Angular-cli: d3.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, angular, angular-cli

I am trying following code to make responsive chart with D3-4.2.2.

```
import * as D3 from 'd3';

let d3:any = D3;

var container = d3.getElementsByTagName('line-graph'),
  width = container[0].offsetWidth,
  height = container[0].offsetHeight;

var svg = d3.select(this.htmlElement).append("svg")
  .attr("class", "line-graph")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + Math.min(width, height) + ' ' + Math.min(width, height))
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin')
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + Math.min(width, height) / 2 + "," + Math.min(width, height) / 2 + ")");
```

Browser console gives

```
d3.getElementsByTagName is not a function
```

Any suggestion are appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: I am not sure if this is the same issue but her is a link of a stack answer  that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848368/typeerror-getelementsbytagname-is-not-a-function-issue

Answer (score 0):

Change: `d3.getElementsByTagName('line-graph')`
to: `d3.select('line-graph')`

Answer (score 0):

There is no function `getElementsByTagName` in D3.js. This is a native JavaScript method of the document object. Thus, you have to use `document`:

```
var container = document.getElementsByTagName('line-graph'),
    width = container[0].offsetWidth,
    height = container[0].offsetHeight;
```

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a node list, and that's why you need the index (in your case, [0]) after `container`.

Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName

PS: I never heard about a tag named "line-graph". Maybe you want `getElementsByClassName`, or `getElementById`.